# is there a way to permanently cache a text file into memory (php)?

Tags: php, caching

I am creating a site that allows users to search a static text file.

The file is large static data txt file (10mb) that needed to be access/read every time a user searches (which is hopefully often).

Is there a way/technique that loads the content of the file and stored it in memory (and assigned a variable to it) permanently so that it would speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing could be permanently in RAM ;)

But if you've already `APC` installed, you can store it in there, or use `memcached` or `Redis`.

Using `APC` is the preferable way, cause you'll get opcode cache as well, which give you a performance boost, and it's just a PHP module. No need to setup another daemon.

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know how apc works.  Assume that the server has apc installed, how does it work?  Right now, every time the script runs, I use file_get_contents to load the file into the variable.  How do I use apc to "store" the content of the file, what are the php codes to access the stored apc content?

Comment: `APC` provides two functions, `apc_store()`, and `apc_fetch()`. Something like `apc_store("content", file_get_contents($filename))`, and later you can retrieve it via `apc_fetch("content")`.

Comment: There's also `apc_exists()` which let you know if desired key is already stored in cache or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the php [shared memory functions?](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php)  Another possibility might to to use a [RAM Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the entire file contents into a in-memory string variable.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am doing right now.  I just want know how to not do that every time the script runs.

Comment: This answer is not helpful, because the OP wants the file to be cached inside the RAM, significantly reducing reads from HDD or SSD.